# Cannot get AlarmManager to work at all on Galaxy III or an emulator

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm

I've browse two dozens samples, articles and so on trying to see why my code won't work.  I have a very simple broadcast listener I'm trying to call with an alarm manager.  Here's my code:

Main Activity onCreate and function (MapsActivity.java)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(240 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(80 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_for_beer);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bar = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SearchBeer.class);
            bar.putExtra("tloc", Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) + "," + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            startActivity(bar);
        }
    });
    startNotes();
}

public void startNotes() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, BeerNotes.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MapsActivity.this, 12345, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (5 * 1000), 5 * 1000, pintent);

}
```

My BroadcastReceiver ... I've commented out code I'm going to want to do and just trying to get a log right now and I'm getting nothing.

```
package com.tapmap.app.tapmapapp;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class BeerNotes extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Exception exception;
private HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
public InputStream in;
private String total;
private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30;
private static final String APP_TAG = "LOG: ";
private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i(APP_TAG, "onReceive() called");
    /*
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://fltapmap.com/notes.php");
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            try {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                total = "";
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total += line + "\n";
                }
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                Log.i("TOTAL NOTES", total);
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                Log.i("MALFORMED1", ioe.getMessage());
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.i("MALFORMED2", ioe.getMessage());
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ioex) {
        Log.i("MALFORMED3", ioex.getMessage());
    }
    */
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tapmap.app.tapmapapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.javapapers.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAksheZLMAALUfLHKWOsfTFCz7iP_KwpCE" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BarBrewry"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bar_brewry"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchBeer"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_beer"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewBeer"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_beer"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider934301593259187"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.tapmap.app.tapmapapp.BeerNotes"></receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `PendingIntent.getService()` to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`

**EDIT**

I notice the commented code in your `BroadcastReceiver` will try to make a network request. This will cause your app to crash with a `NetworkOnMainThread` exception. I recommend you create a class that extends `IntentService` and do your network operations inside of `onHandleIntent()` instead. In that case, you can use `PendingIntent.getService()` to have the intent go to the service.

Comment: Switched it to an IntentService and working great :)